# Data view added in the master page breaks in the sub site where Data View uses the list of site collection

Tags: data-view-web-part

I have create a masterpage of a publishing site and insert a DVWP as https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/A-MegaMenu-for-SharePoint-2010-Using-a-DVWP-and-a-List.aspx

Its working fine for the same site pages but as soon i create a subsite. i get following error on the pages

> List does not exist.
>
> The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may
>   have been deleted by another user.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: a97e2606-dc35-4e21-9db1-8878598c42ac
>
> Date and Time: 11/3/2013 2:07:04 PM

After googling the issue i found that its because my subsite is CANNOT reference to the list in parent site. I also found a way to fix which is 
http://www.neilrichards.net/ramble/dataview-web-parts-in-your-master-page-cause-errors-on-subsites

but nothing seem to be working for me on Sharepoint 2010, can any one help?